# Visualizing data model using data Studio 4.1

Tags: db2, entity-relationship, datamodel, ibm-data-studio

I want to generate ER - Diagram for existing database. I created .dbm file but in diagram I see only table names all in a row. I am not able to see columns and relationship between tables. 
How can i see ER- diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got answer in data studio forum.

Columns can be displayed by changing the properties view. Click a blank area of the diagram and in the filtering tab of the properties and change the display options. To see relationship right click on blank space and click on show implicit relationships.